# Thyristor Power Loss

Tags: power-electronics, thyristor

i want to calculate the power loss of a thyristor with datasheet's parameters and i found this formula from here [Application Note](https://library.e.abb.com/public/eca170669d212ea3c12574790029fcf4/Switching%20losses%20for%20Thyristor_5SYA%202055-01NewLay.pdf):

Conduction loss:

[image]

Total loss:

[image]

How can i calculate the power loss if i have 30° as my firing angle? What is the effect of firing angle on conduction loss or switching loss?

The questions are already answered by @SpehrePefhany, but now i have sample excercise:

Thyristor's parameters:

- Vt0 = 1,5 V
- rt = 0,5 mΩ
- The thyristor carries a rectified sinusoidal current with an amplitude of    I=300A
- Firing angle α = 30°

[image]

Conduction loss:

Itα = (I / 2π ) * (1+cos(α)) = (300A / 2π) * (1+cos(30)) = 49,62 A

Itavg = Itα / π = 15,79 A

Itrms = Itα / 2 = 24,81 A

Pvd = Vt0 . Itavg + rt . I²trms = 1,5 V * 15,79 A + 0,5 mΩ * (24,81 A)² = 23,99 W

Please let me know if this is a correct calculation.

Comment: I'd just use a simulator.

Comment: If you can write an equation for the load current as a function of time you can integrate that to get average and integrate the square to eventually find the RMS current, you know the switching frequency then the other characteristics are from the thyristor datasheet.

Comment: So, does it mean, that firing angle will only effect the current on conduction loss? and it doesn't have any effect on switching loss?

Comment: Y es. The switching frequency affects the switching loss, the firing angle (assuming a phase control situation) affects only the conduction loss (through the forward drop and ohmic I^2R losses).

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a near-exact duplicate of [this previously-deleted question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/606775/firing-angle-of-thyristor) by the same user. @Laz if you have new information for a question, use the edit button, not the delete button.

Comment: @Hearth I'm sorry. will do it better next time.